# No overload takes '0' arguments [c#]

Tags: c#, overloading

I am getting an error of "No overload takes 0 args" at the Start(); line in my main method.  I do not know how to fix it, and I've searched around and couldn't find anything.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            public static void main(string[] args)
            {
                Start();
            }

            public static string Start(string move)
            {



                Console.Write("");
                string gameType = Console.ReadLine();

                if (gameType == "s")
                {

                    Console.Write("");
                begin:
                    Console.Write("\nEnter your move: ");
                    move = Console.ReadLine();


                    switch (move)
                    {
                        case "r":
                            Console.Write("s");
                            Console.ReadLine();

                            break;
                        case "s":
                            Console.Write("");
                            Console.ReadLine();

                            break;
                        case "f":
                            Console.Write("");
                            Console.ReadLine();

                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.Write("\nInvalid move, try again\n\n");


   goto begin;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
                return move;
            }
            else
            {
                return move;
            }
        }


        static string Genius(string genius, string move)
        {
            Console.Write(move);
            return genius;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Replace your goto with a while loop before a [velociraptor eats you](http://xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: Generally, your first program should be something along the lines of Hello World...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method call to Start should should be

```
Start("Something");
```

Edit: as others have pointed out: there is no point in passing anything to Start(). The move value passed in is ignored and replaced by whatever is read from the console. Therefore I suggest simply removing the argument from the Start() method signature so it just reads

```
public static string Start()
```

Comment: Except that whatever is passed in will be replaced by `move = Console.ReadLine();` So you might as well call `Start(null)`.

Comment: Heh hadn't noticed. In fact, the answer to the original question is probably then "remove the argument to the Start() method" :D

Answer (score 2):

Since you are reading the move from the console, remove the `string move` from the parameter definition of Start and move it inside as a local variable and it should be fine:

```
public static string Start()
        { string move;
          ...
```

And btw, **your main should be Main** - in c# the main should have a capital M!

I recommend you read some basics of C#.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this is your method call:

```
 Start();
```

and this is the method's signature:

```
 public static string Start(string move)
```

There is a mismatch between them...

Comment: I'm trying to run my Start method after the main one, would this do it?

Comment: No. You declared an argument ``move`` that must be passed to the method. Anders already gave you the exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Start(arg) should be like:

```
private static string Start()
{
   string move = null;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The start method expects a string as a parameter:

Examples:
Start("r");
Start("s");
Start("f");

Comment: Now it says Error 1 Program 'C:\Users\Zack\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\obj\x86\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point ConsoleApplication1

Comment: That's because `Main` should be capitalized and your `main` method is not.

Answer (score 0):

You should either pass an argument when Start() is called (as Anders suggested) or you should remove the argument from Start() and declare it as a local variable instead:

```
    public static string Start()
    {
        string move = string.Empty;
```